# High working set size in dotnet under Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, out-of-memory

We have an application running under kubernetes that is NET6.0.  This application is a controller and starts up 10 worker processes.  The issue we are experiencing is that frequently these worker processes are being killed by kubernetes and have the exit code of 137.  From my research that indicates that they were kill because they are consuming too much memory.

To make this issue further difficult to troubleshoot, it only happens in our production environment after a period of time.  Our production environment is also very locked down, the docker images all run with a readonly root filesystem, with a non-root user and very low priviledges.  So to monitor the application we created a dashboard that reports various things, the two I will focus on are these pieces of data:

```
            DotnetTotalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024),
            WorkingSetSize = process.WorkingSet64 / (1024 * 1024),
```

The interesting thing is that the "DotnetTotalMemory" ranges anywhere from 200mb to 400mb, but the "WorkingSetSize" starts out between 400mb to 600mb, but at times it jumps up to 1300mb, even when the "DotnetTotalMemory" is hovering at 200mb.

Our quota is as follows:

```
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: '5'
      memory: 10Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 1250m
      memory: 5Gi
```

From what I have read, the limit amount is recognized as the "available system memory" for dotnet and is passed to it through some mechanism similar to `docker run --memory=XX`, correct?

I switched to Workstation GC and that seems to make them slightly more stable.  Another thing I tried was setting the 'DOTNET_GCConserveMemory' environment variable to '9', again it seems to help some.  But I can't get past the fact that the process seems to have 1100mb+ of memory that is not managed by the GC.  Is there a way for me to reduce the working set used by these processes?

Comment: Have you tried dotnet monitor? It'll allow you to get some detailed metrics [link](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/kubernetes.md)

You can output the metrics into prometheus too :)

Comment: Also I can't find links for the following but I seem to recall that kubernetes will kill a pod that exceeds its requests but not its limit in order to be able to schedule other pods. Given .nets memory limit is based off the pods it *might* help :)

Comment: I believe I tried this a year ago when we migrated from our old cloud to kubernetes.  Several things prevented this from working, first off you have to get special privileges for the container, second we have to disable diagnostics with this variable(COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics) because of the next point, and lastly we run with a readonly filesystem, so we have to disable debugging and profiling support since that feature requires writing to the filesystem.  I will update if this works out but I am not optimistic that this will work.

Comment: At present its using an empty volume, but you could use a persistent volume (i.e. EBS if your using AWS :))